# How to make generic function get object properties based on input in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have Java entity as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "xxxx")
public class User extends AuditableBase<Long> {

  /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5827659402853250569L;

  public static final String FTL = "FTL";

  /** The refer number. */
  @Column(name = "reference_number")
  private String referenceNumber;

  /** The customer id. */
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
  @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
  private Customer customer;

  /** The load Notes. */
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "load")
  @JsonBackReference
  private Set<Notes> notes = new HashSet<>();

  /** The customer location. */
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "customer_location_id")
  @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
  private CustomerLocation customerLocation;

  /** The invoice number. */
  @Column(name = "invoice_number")
  private String invoiceNumber;

  // Lot going

  /**
   * Instantiates a new User.
   */
  public User() {
    super();
  }

  /**
   * Instantiates a new User.
   *
   * @param id
   *          the id
   */
  public User(Long id) {
    super(id);
  }

}
```

I have lot of childs inside the entity, I am getting the object from DAO call

```
User user = userRepository.findById(userId);
```

Now I want to get some user details, based on some if condition referencing to Map.

```
Map<Integer, String> cc = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
cc.put(1, "getCustomer()");
cc.put(2, "getNotes()");
cc.put(3, "getCustomerLocation()");
cc.put(4, "getReferenceNumber()");


for (Entry<Integer, String> map : cc.entrySet()) {

    user.map.getvalue();

}
```

I need to create a generic method for get the user objects based on the map.

How can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand your question, but you could do something like that:

```
        Map<Integer,Method> cc = new HashMap<>();
        cc.put(1, User.class.getDeclaredMethod("getCustomer"));
        cc.put(2, User.class.getDeclaredMethod("getNotes"));
        cc.put(3, User.class.getDeclaredMethod("getCustomerLocation"));
        cc.put(4, User.class.getDeclaredMethod("getReferenceNumber"));

        for (Entry<Integer, Method> map : cc.entrySet()) {
            Integer index = map.getKey();
            Method getter = map.getValue();
            Object value = getter.invoke(user);
            doSomethingUsefulWith(index, value);
        }
```

UPDATE:

you could declare an interface `Getter` like so:

```
public interface Getter<T,R> {
    public R get(T obj);
}
```

And then do something like so:

```
    Map<Integer,Getter<User,?>> cc = new HashMap<>();
    cc.put(1, (u) -> u.getCustomer().getName());
    cc.put(2, (u) -> u.getNotes());
    cc.put(3, (u) -> u.getCustomerLocation());
    cc.put(4, (u) -> u.getReferenceNumber());
    for (Entry<Integer,Getter<User,?>> map : cc.entrySet()) {
        Integer index = map.getKey();
        Getter<User,?> getter = map.getValue();
        Object value = getter.get(user);
        doSomethingUsefulWith(index, value);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks. If I want to get customer Name from getCustomer, is this possible still
?

Comment: @JQuery it wouldn't be that simple because you would have to evaluate an expression instead of just calling a method

Comment: Awesome, Works like charm... Thanks @Maurice